# Django field extending UserCreationForm not showing up in view

Tags: python, django, forms, view

What I'm trying to accomplish is to extend UserCreationForm to add an e-mail field for each user when they sign- up. Currently I have a form from UserCreationForm with username and password but no e-mail. I extend it with the forms.py file and implement it in my views.py. But when I run tests and look at the signup page the e-mail field is not found.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login as auth_login
from .forms import SignUpForm

# Create your views here.
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            auth_login(request, user)
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(max_length = 254, required = True, widget = forms.EmailInput())
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

form.html:

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for field in form %}
  <div class="form-group">
    {{ field.label_tag }}

    {% if form.is_bound %}
      {% if field.errors %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ error }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid" %}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">
        {{ field.help_text|safe }}
      </small>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Now, when I actually go to the sign in page it only presents Username and password fields. However, when I refresh the page or send an invalid form, the e-mail field shows up when the form reloads. It's confirmed that the field is not showing up on initial load when I run tests and get an assertion error:

```
AssertionError: 0 != 1 : Found 0 instances of 'type="email"' in response (expected 1)
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the said behavior. You should add the failing test spec to your question

Comment: Hello, this was resolved by using django-widgets-improved instead of the old django-widgets-tweaks